# Detect if Test Failed in tearDown() Function - Xcode UIAutomation, XCTest, Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I have some logs I want updated if a test passes and some different logs updated if a test passes. How can I determine if the test was a pass or fail in the tearDown() method?

```
override func tearDown() {
    super.tearDown()
    // Would like an if statement here to update my logs but not sure how to detect the state
    if fail {
        log.update("failed")
    } else if !fail {
        log.update("success")
    }

}
```

Comment: On this same note, is there a way to detect if it's the last test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`testRun?.failureCount` should be greater than 0 if the test failed:

```
override func tearDown() {
    super.tearDown()

    if testRun?.failureCount > 0 {
        log.update("failed")
    } else {
        log.update("success")
    }

}
```

its a little harder to figure out if this teardown is the last teardown but an easy way to run a teardown after your last test is:

```
override class func tearDown() {
    super.tearDown

    // Do Something after all tests have ran
}
```

Comment: If statement should also check if `unexpectedExceptionCount` is greater than zero.

Comment: `totalFailureCount` catches _all_ failures & exceptions